# Poetry add dependency that uses cython

Tags: python, cython, python-packaging, python-poetry

I have a project which needs to depend on the latest commit of [pysam](https://github.com/pysam-developers/pysam), because I'm working in python 3.11.

This means building the package from source, so I do the following:

`poetry add git+https://github.com/pysam-developers/pysam`

However, I get an error which I think boils down to poetry not including cython in the build environment:

```
Unable to determine package info for path: /Users/agreen/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/rnacentral-pipeline-GU-1IkEM-py3.11/src/pysam

Fallback egg_info generation failed.

Command ['/var/folders/sg/3858brmd79z4rz781g0q__940000gp/T/tmpw8auvhsm/.venv/bin/python', 'setup.py', 'egg_info'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
# pysam: no cython available - using pre-compiled C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/agreen/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/rnacentral-pipeline-GU-1IkEM-py3.11/src/pysam/setup.py", line 345, in <module>
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: no cython installed, but can not find pysam/libchtslib.c.Make sure that cython is installed when building from the repository
```

Cython is definitely installed, its in the [pyproject.toml](https://gist.github.com/afg1/f77cc9e08f69a417a5dba49fc636b660), and I can call it from the poetry shell, or import it in a python started in the poetry virtualenv. However, If I use the python from the command poetry is running, then indeed cython is not available.

I think I'm missing some configuration of the build, or some extra option to `poetry add`. The documentation isn't particularly clear about this use of cython - as far as I can tell it's all about using cython in the package I'm writing, which is not quite what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Cython* is a build dependency of *pysam*, but apparently *pysam* does not have a `pyproject.toml` and thus does not declare its build dependencies (*Cython* and maybe others). So this is a dead end.

If I were you I would build a *wheel* of *pysam* myself and tell *Poetry* to use this *wheel* until *pysam* releases *wheels* for Python 3.11 on *PyPI* themselves. Or I would use Python 3.10.

---

It seems like it is being worked on: https://github.com/pysam-developers/pysam/pull/1168

Comment: Yeah, I decided to try and implement a minimal `pyproject.toml` since I wanted to use it with python 3.11, so for now I'm just building off my own fork. Thanks for your help!